# How to search and replace across multiple word documents in the same folder?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I've tried to use the below code which I found on this conversation [How To Search And Replace Across Multiple Files In Word?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69530387/how-to-search-and-replace-across-multiple-files-in-word) supplied by Charles Kenyon. However, it doesn't seem to work for me. I've enabled macros on my word and added the below code as a new module in Macros. When I go to replace all, it'll replace the text as per normal, but after doing this, when I open up the other macros enabled word doc, I find that the same text is still in these docs, without being replaced. Am I doing something wrong? Namely, I also wish to add a wildcard entry into my replace all, will the below code work or can someone suggest a better alternative?  I have tested the below code with and without wildcard entries to no avail.  I've also tried the code on this page in my macros but it also didn't work [How to find and replace a text in multiple Word documents using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65852638/how-to-find-and-replace-a-text-in-multiple-word-documents-using-vba)Thanks for any help!

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub BatchReplaceAll()

    Dim FirstLoop As Boolean
    Dim myFile As String
    Dim PathToUse As String
    Dim myDoc As Document
    Dim Response As Long

    PathToUse = "C:\Test\"

    'Error handler to handle error generated whenever
    'the FindReplace dialog is closed

    On Error Resume Next

    'Close all open documents before beginning

    Documents.Close SaveChanges:=wdPromptToSaveChanges

    'Boolean expression to test whether first loop
    'This is used so that the FindReplace dialog will
    'only be displayed for the first document

    FirstLoop = True

    'Set the directory and type of file to batch process

    myFile = Dir$(PathToUse & "*.doc")

    While myFile <> ""

        'Open document
        Set myDoc = Documents.Open(PathToUse & myFile)

        If FirstLoop Then

            'Display dialog on first loop only

            Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace).Show

            FirstLoop = False

            Response = MsgBox("Do you want to process " & _
            "the rest of the files in this folder", vbYesNo)
            If Response = vbNo Then Exit Sub

        Else

            'On subsequent loops (files), a ReplaceAll is
            'executed with the original settings and without
            'displaying the dialog box again

            With Dialogs(wdDialogEditReplace)
                .ReplaceAll = 1
                .Execute
            End With

        End If

        'Close the modified document after saving changes

        myDoc.Close SaveChanges:=wdSaveChanges

        'Next file in folder

        myFile = Dir$()

    Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: First you need to remove `On Error Resume Next`. This line hides **all** error messages, but the errors still occur, you just cannot see their messages. So if you cannot see them you cannot fix your errors and if you don't fix them (who would guess that) your code does not do what you expect. • This line is evil the way you use it. Remove it and fix the errors you get (or tell us which errors you get and in which line if you need assistance). • If you are interested in proper error handling: [VBA Error Handling – A Complete Guide](https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-error-handling)

Comment: See, for example: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/16209-run-macro-multiple-docx-files.html, https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/4054-replace-text-multiple-documents.html, https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/40245-need-vba-code-find-replace-between-two.html, & https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/22669-created-vba-find-replace-body-header-footer.html